# override ::-webkit-scrollbar for a specific div in my react project

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have used the below code to hide all scrollbar in React project and I want to keep it that way but for a specific div I want a scroll bar to be displayed overriding the below code how can I do that

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

the div that I don't want the above code to have

```html
<div className="tabview"></div>
```

I want something like this

```css
.tabview::-Webkit-scrollbar {  //I want something like this to override the code that has been given to the entire project
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS `not` keyword.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```css
.box, .tabview {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
}
  

div:not(.tabview)::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabview">
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this doenot woek for me as i said i wanted to override the  ::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;} just for a div in my entire projct

Comment: This will not run `display:none` for the `.tabview` class. I'm not sure what part is incorrect. Do you specifically need to overwrite it or do you just want `display:none` to not occur on certain classes.

Comment: i want::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;} for my entire project but i want to exclude  tabview from it

Comment: pls note i have a very big project

Comment: That is what this is doing. tabview has a scroll bar and no other div's in the entire project will have one.

Comment: i tryed as u asked u  see the screenshots i have added `div:not(.tabview)::-webkit-scrollbar` is not getting even read in browser

Comment: `tabView` needs to be on the same element that has the `overflow` on it. Maybe just create a new class called `keepScroll` and add that wherever you want to keep them.  `div:not(.keepScroll)::-webkit-scrollbar`

Comment: i added what u did i moved the  overflow  in to tabview div still `div:not(.keepScroll)::-webkit-scrollbar` did not got read by browser

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `tabview` styling by writing a `not` pseudoclass, as:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar:not(.tabview){
  display: none;
}
```

Alternatively, you can mark the style as `!important` or add more specificity.

```css
.tabview::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: block !important;
}
```

Also make sure that `tabview` is the container div.

Comment: .tabview ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block!important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}                                                                                                                                                            i tryed this but no scroll bar is appearing but when i inspect  elemect in browser and check the code in pesodo ::-webkit-scrollbar  the above code is coming where both code is working when i uncheck the display none the scrollbar appears

Comment: @meenucd There shouldn't be space after `.tabview` , it should be `.tabview::-webkit-scrollbar { display: block!important; }` . Also please re-check if `tabview` is the parent wrapper in which the scrollbar is coming.

Comment: NeEraj  i have added a image will show what my probelm is

Comment: display: none; is not getting overridden

Comment: @meenucd Try removing the class `tabview` from div and add it to the table.

Comment: i tryed it did not work

Comment: @meenucd I've updated the answer. Please try it with the `not` pseudoclass.

Comment: still no luck  shoulls i add thiss also  .tabview::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: block !important;
}

Comment: No need to add that. We're specifying the style using [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudoclass which excludes `tabview` class.

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:not(.tabview) {
  display: none;
}`   now my code is like this still                                                                                               `::-webkit-scrollbar:not(.tabview) {
  display: none;
}` is not getiing read                                                                                                               `::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}  ` is still active

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar:not(.tabview) {   display: none; } this is not displayed in inspect element

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Remove `overflow:scroll;` from table inline style. Because you already hide scrollbar for all and you enable scroll on class `.tabview` using your old css. And you apply scroll in Table which is causes problem.

[image]

**Method- 1**

So, use below `CSS` and not use `!important` in it.

```
.tabview{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tabview::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: block;
}
```

Change `max-height` according your needs.

**Method-2**

Or just use below css

```
.tabview table::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: block;
}
```